# Intel AVX performs slower than Scalar Code

Tags: c, intel, sse, simd, avx

I'm trying to compare the performance between scalar code and Intel AVX (SIMD) code compiling with the -O3 flag.

After running the programs I see huge performance difference between them.
I use 4 functions:
* Sum
* Count
* Min
* Max
For all scalar executions the result time I retrieve is 0.000001 sec (average, 11 executions of each case) in contrast to 0.043958 sec for AVXSum, AVXMin, AVXMax (Count case gives me the same fast result for both executions).

I tried to have a deeper look in the assembly code of scalar functions. To my surprise I discovered that gcc generates the same assembly code for ScalarSum, ScalarCount, ScalarMin, ScalarMax.

Since a RAW dependency happens, I was expecting some delay in the execution times. Having a closer look to the Branch misses number, they are quite close (i.e: 772,548,846 branch-misses and  0.044221sec average for AVXMin  ,  772,656,995 branch-misses 0.000000 sec average for ScalarMin).

The input (relation) is an array of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 elements (rel_size).
In the main function I initialize and randomize the input array (rand() is user and Fisher Yates algorithm is implemented). I believe that no compile time calculation is happening, but I can not explain such a big performance difference.

Bellow, I attach the generated assembly code for scalar case (same for all cases, as I mentioned). Moreover, I attach AVXMin and ScalarMin C codes.

```
    .file   "scalarMin.c"  
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits  
.LCOLDB1:  
    .text  
.LHOTB1:  
    .p2align 4,,15  
    .globl  scalar_min  
    .type   scalar_min, @function
scalar_min:
.LFB38:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 3, -16
    call    clock
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    call    clock
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    subq    %rbx, %rax
    popq    %rbx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    cvtsi2sdq   %rax, %xmm0
    divsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE38:
    .size   scalar_min, .-scalar_min
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .text
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1093567616
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Intel AVX Min function:

```
double avx_min(int32_t** relation, int32_t rel_size){

  clock_t t;
  __m256i input_buffer;
  __m256i min = _mm256_set_epi32(INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX);
  t = clock();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rel_size ; i += 8){
    input_buffer = _mm256_stream_load_si256((__m256i*)&(*relation)[i]);
    min = _mm256_min_epi32(min, input_buffer);
  }
  t = clock() - t;
  return ((double) t) /CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Scalar Min function:

```
double scalar_min(int32_t** relation, int32_t rel_size){
  clock_t t;
  int32_t min = INT32_MAX;
  t = clock();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rel_size ; i++){
    if( (*relation)[i] < min ){
     min = (*relation)[i];
    }
  }
  t = clock() - t;
  return ((double) t) /CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Thank you in advance for you help :)

Comment: Probably gcc optimized away the scalar code, because you didn't use the results in any way? What happens if you print the value of `min` at the end of the scalar code and at the end of the AVX code?

Comment: @wim You saved my day mister!! This parameter did not cross my mind !!! Having a first look, the returning time result is about 0.408051 sec, which is quite logic compared to other results I have. I hope I'll come back to confirm it one more time. Thank you again for your time and your contribution!

Comment: There's no "probably" about it.  The asm shows back-to-back calls to `clock`, only saving the return value from RAX.  Your answer is right there in your question.  If your benchmark doesn't scale with the repeat-count or problem size, or if it's coming out at exactly 0 microseconds, it's optimizing away.